Create movable tooltip with ListViewItem being dragged to another ListView
I have one source ListView that has items that are drag-able to 2 other ListViews. I want a movable tooltip and an icon (Icon is either green arrow for allowable and a red circle with a slash in it for non-allowable).
Basically,
if (some_condition) allow the drop, else disallow it. The drag and drop already works based on that condition but the movable tooltip would be helpful.

How "movable" is the tooltip supposed to be?

Well, it really doesn't have to be movable. But I'd like a tooltip on the target upon drag enter or drag over

If so, edit your question. And add what you tried so far.

Wpf drag and drop: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/drag-and-drop-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8
